# Desktop-inside-desktop wierd behavior

Tags: unity

So: brand new installation of 14.04 on my dad's all-in-one HP. Ubuntu starts up for the first time, and i see a wierd looking desktop for which the best words to describe it is sth like desktop-inside-desktop ([you can see it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MD2w.jpg)). To understand why i call it desktop-inside-desktop i took [the second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aagys.jpg) while dragging the unity icons downwards, and you can clearly see sth like there is a second unity bar behind it.

I have no clue what's going on, although i admit, it's quite funny to look at (and artistically interesting).

Can anyone help?